# Adding a line to a blank R Plot

Tags: r, ggplot2, plot

So I have the following code that produced a blank canvas:

```
plot(1, type="n", xlab="Output", ylab="Real Interest Rate", xlim=c(9800, 10400), ylim=c(0.01, 0.07))
```

Now I am wondering how to get a line on the graph intersecting points (10000, 0.05) and (10200, 0.03).

I only want the line on my plot.

Any help is greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Base R - use the `lines()` function.

```
x <- c(10000, 10200)
y <- c(0.05, 0.03)
plot(1, 
     type="n", 
     xlab="Output", 
     ylab="Real Interest Rate", 
     xlim=c(9800, 10400), 
     ylim=c(0.01, 0.07))
lines(x, y)
```

[image]

In `ggplot2`, use `geom_line()`.

```
library(ggplot2)
x <- c(10000, 10200)
y <- c(0.05, 0.03)
ggplot(data.frame(x, y), aes(x, y)) + 
  geom_line() +
  scale_x_continuous(name = "Output", 
                     limits = c(9800, 10400), 
                     breaks = seq(9800, 10400, 100) +
  scale_y_continuous(name = "Real Interest Rate", 
                     limits = c(0.01, 0.07), 
                     breaks = seq(0.01, 0.07, 0.02)) +
  theme_bw()
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

A very simple version.

## make a very simple plot

```
x <- c(10000,10200)
y <- c(0.05, 0.03)
plot(x,y,type="b",xlab="Output", ylab="Real Interest Rate",xlim=c(9800, 10400), ylim=c(0.01, 0.07))
```

[image: plot]